# Excel saves tab delimited files without newline (UNIX/Mac os X)

Tags: macos, excel, perl, unix, newline

This is a common issue I have and my solution is a bit brash. So I'm looking for a quick fix and explanation of the problem.

The problem is that when I decide to save a spreadsheet in excel (mac 2011) as a tab delimited file it seems to do it perfectly fine. Until I try to parse the file line by line using Perl. For some reason it slurps the whole document in one line.

My brutish solution is to open the file in a web browser and copy and paste the information into the tab delimited file in TextEdit (I never use rich text format). I tried introducing a newline in the end of the file before doing this fix and it does not resolve the issue.

What's going on here? An explanation would be appreciated.

~Thanks!~

Comment: What are the newlines in the output, and which do you expect? `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`? The issue you describe could occur if the output contains `\n` line endings (standard in Unix), and you're actually expecting the `\r\n` Windows line endings. Please check what's actually there.

Comment: When I use `less` I see this character `^M`

Comment: Yet another reason why I hate Microsoft.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the actual character codes that define new lines on different systems.  Windows systems commonly use a CarriageReturn+LineFeed (CRLF) and *NIX systems use only a LineFeed (LF).

These characters can be represented in RegEx as **\r\n** or **\n** (respectively).

Sometimes, to hash through a text file, you need to parse New Line characters.  Try this for DOS-to-UNIX in **perl**:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input.file
```

or, for UNIX-to-DOS using **sed**:

```
$ sed 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" input.txt > output.txt
```

or, for DOS-to-UNIX using **sed**:

```
$ sed 's/^M$//' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I was trying to think how this can cause his problem, and I  don't see how it can. I suspect he's going *to* Windows instead.

Comment: I'm staying in UNIX, and the same Mac computer. I have done the perl fix and it worked! Thanks! But do you know if it's possible for Excel to save documents formatted for UNIX? I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac so you would think it should be able to do it.

Comment: My guess is that Microsoft did not include/enable that functionality, trying to maximize compatibility with their Windows-based Office products instead.

Comment: Excel 2011 on mac is saving text files (ie tsv) using only the carriage return to separate lines `\r`. This used to be standard on Mac OS 9, but since OS X the standard convention is to use the Unix newline `\n`. Maybe Microsoft will become compliant with this standard in the future? One can dream...

Comment: @AndrewJesaitis is right - the specific problem here is that Excel saves .csv files with `\r` line endings, which isn't the right convention on OS X. So, to correct @epluribusunix 's answer, the correct Perl one-liner would be: `perl -pi -e 's/\r/\n/g' input.file`

Answer (score 7):

Found a pretty simple solution to this. Copy data from Excel to clipboard, paste it into a google spreadsheet. Download google spreadsheet file as a 'tab-separated values .tsv'. This gets around the problem and you have tab delimiters with an end of line for each line.﻿

Comment: Similarly, in Excel for Mac you can work around this problem by copying all in Excel and pasting into Sublime Text.  Save that file, and newlines are properly formed.

Comment: Awesome answer!!! Thanks Anders! You'd think this would be built into Excel somewhere, especially now that we are like 10 versions ahead of where we were when you wrote this!

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution ...

- for a tab-delimited file, save the document as a `Windows Formatted Text (.txt)` file type
- for a comma-separated file, save the document as a `Windows Comma Separated (.csv)' file type

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a useful regex pattern `\R` which will match any common line ending. It actually matches any vertical whitespace -- the same as `\v` -- or the CR LF combination, so it's the same as `\r\n|\v`

This is useful here because you can slurp your entire file into a single scalar and then `split /\R/`, which will give you a list of file records, already `chomp`ed (if you want to keep the line terminators you can `split /\R\K/` instead

Another option is the [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::eol) module. It provides a new Perl IO layer that will normalize line endings no matter what the contents of the file are

Once you have loaded the module with `use PerlIO::eol` you can use it in an `open` statement

```
open my $fh, '<:eol(LF)', 'myfile.tsv' or die $!;
```

or you can use the [`open`](https://metacpan.org/pod/open) pragma to set it as the default layer for all input file handles

```
use open IN  => ':raw:eol(LF)';
```

which will work fine with an input file from any platform