# PHP , fgets return full content of file

Tags: php, fgets, fgetcsv

I have a csv file, which have +100 lines, but I tried many sample codes, always $line returning full content of file rather line by line. I tried many sample php codes, I think there is problem with file data, but when I am opening csv file I can see 100s of lines.

```
<?php
    $file_handle = fopen("mycsv.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $line = fgets($file_handle);
       echo $line . "<br>";
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    ?>
```

Any help please

Kind Regards

Comment: Try `$file_handle = file("mycsv.txt");` that should return an array where each element is a line from the file.

Comment: It is returning the data line by line, use view source to see it.

Comment: or just use the csv specific functions

Comment: What does `var_dump($line)` show you?

Comment: @RatHat tried and same

Comment: view source showing same all file content, tried echo $line . "FFFFF"; but got only printed once.
var_dump shows all

Comment: Was the csv file created in a mac or linux?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem with new lines in your csv file. Please check the following thread:

[Excel saves tab delimited files without newline (UNIX/Mac os X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052168/excel-saves-tab-delimited-files-without-newline-unix-mac-os-x)